# Extract lines from a text file with one column equal to the maximum

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a text file (with header line) called file.txt.
I am trying to extract the lines equal to the maximum value of a specific column (I do not know what the max value is):

```
ID t1 q1 t2 q2 q3 
1 f 45 ex 1 45
2 r 47 tr 1 33
3 r 33 ex 2 44
4 f 44 s 0 55
5 e 32 ex 0 54
6 f 34 tr 2 46
```

I need to find the maximum value of column $5 and then print only the lines with column 5 equal to this number:

```
3 r 33 ex 2 44
6 f 34 tr 2 46
```

I think the following code works, but my file is huge and it takes a vary long time, so I am looking for a faster solution (maybe using sort?):

This is what I have for now:

Fist find the max value:

```
max=`awk '{print $5}' file.txt | sort -nr | sed -n 2p`
```

Then select the lines where column 5 is equal to this value:

```
awk 'NR>1' file.txt|while read LINE; do value=`echo $LINE|awk '{print $5}'`; if [ $value -eq $max ]; then echo $LINE >> test.txt; fi; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to read the file once to get `max` and then again to print the relevant lines:

```
max=$(awk 'NR>1 && $5>max {max=$5}; END{print max}' file.txt) && 
 awk -v max="$max" '$5==max' file.txt
```

Or, more concisely:

```
awk -v m="$(awk '(NR>1 && $5>m){m=$5};END{print m}' file.txt)"  '$5==m' file.txt
```

The trick here is awk's `-v` flag which allows you to pass a variable to `awk`. In this case, I am first calculating the max value and then giving it to `awk` as variable `max`.

Comment: Thank you! All these work, I just accepted the first code since it was more in line with what I had tried so I understand it better. Thank a lot to all!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly typical problem for which an idiomatic awk solution involving two passes over the file exists. In the first pass, identify the max value for `$5` and in the second, extract records that contain that max value in `$5`. Here's a quick example.

```
awk 'NR == FNR && NR > 1{max = max < $5? $5: max; next}; $5 == max{print}' file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! Both these methods work, I find this a bit hard to understand because I am a beginner…I am having a hard time making sense mostly of the piece inside brackets (and why do you repeat the input file twice?). But it does the job perfectly...

Comment: @user971102, sure. Since terdon has done a great job of providing a clear explanation, you should accept his answer

Answer (score 1):

If memory usage is not really an issue, a one-pass version in perl would probably be:

```
perl -ane 'END { $"=""; print "@res"; } if($F[4] =~ /^\d+/ and $F[4] > $max) { 
    $max = $F[4]; @res = (); } push @res, $_ if($F[4] =~ /^\d+$/ and $max == $F[4]);' infile
```

`-n` tells perl to process the `infile` one line at a time passing each line to the commands specified in `-e`. The `-a` tells perl to expand each line around the field separator (this defaults to space), and assign this to an array called `@F`. The upshot is for every line we can process it and use `$F[n]` to refer to the nth element of that line.

The perl itself:

```
END { $"=""; print "@res"; } # at the end of execution set the field separator to
                             # empty and print the contents of @res, which includes
                             # newlines when the matching rows were stored

if($F[4] =~ /^\d+/ and $F[4] > $max) {  # if the 5th element of the line is solely a
    $max = $F[4]; @res = ();            # number and it's greater than $max (which
}                                       # starts as undefined), set $max to this number
                                        # and empty the @res results array.

push @res, $_                                  # push this line to @res ...
     if($F[4] =~ /^\d+$/ and $max == $F[4]);   # IF the 5th element is solely a 
                                               # number and equal to $max
```

The logic is that `$max` starts as undefined and the `@res` array empty. The first time we find a number in column 5, we store this in `$max` and empty `@res`. This also has the side effect of emptying `@res` if we find a new maximum value in column 5 on following rows. As a separate check, if column 5 is equal to `$max` add this line to `@res` (store lines with the present maximum value). Repeat for all lines, and then the `END { }` block is executed which prints the contents of the `@res` results array without the leading space field separator normally set in `$"`.

This could also probably be achieved in `awk`, but my `awk-fu` is not that great!

Answer (score 1):

Sort the file with values in descending order, then print the lines from the top until the value changes.

```
sort -k 5n | awk 'NR==1 {max=$5} $5!=max {quit} {print}'
```